# What are the effects of missing questions on an FAA Written exam?

Tags: faa-knowledge-test, designated-examiner

I took my Instrument Rating written exam this morning and scored an 85% (which is 51/60). Not bad, but I am worried about what this might bring about in the future. If I remember correctly for my private written, I got a 73%, and not only did I have to review everything with my instructor, but the DPE asked a question from every category I missed. Should I expect the same from my instrument DPE? That wouldn't be too big of a hurdle. The main thing I am worried about is the distant future. Do airlines have access to these scores?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking if airlines have access to your score, whether they look and if it may matter?

Comment: I suppose yes... sorry I will edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An airline wants to see that you have the ratings and the hours, which is demonstrated by your certificate, and your logbook.  While a logbook may be scrutinized, I've never heard of an airline having any way to find out what your score was on your writtens.  Heck, if they were to ask me, I wouldn't even have any idea what the scores were, nor where to research them.

Since the report on the exam is there with you at the checkride, it's not surprising that the DPE had access to that info, but once you're beyond that stage, you have the certificate, and so you met the standard, and that's the fact, end of story.

I wouldn't worry about the score.

Comment: Good to hear! Does the DPE really care either? The only thing my Private DPE said was "wow, you missed a lot." and then asked a question from each category and that was that.

Comment: I think the level of "care" that your Private DPE showed is about all you should expect.  You passed the written, and he's there to administer the checkride.  He can't bust you for the ground eval because of the score on the written, but he can use the categories to guide his questions somewhat.  Brush up on those categories in preparation for the ground eval, and you should be fine.

Comment: @TylerYoung The DPE is *required* to ask you at least one question for each area of deficiency to establish that you  addressed it. But they *should* hit all the key areas anyway; if you haven’t already, review the ACS to understand what to expect—and regardless of your score, be prepared to cover every single task listed.

Answer (score 4):

[Yes, the DPE cares and yes the DPE must test you on deficient areas](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8900.2C.pdf) (bolded for emphasis),

> d. Airman Knowledge Test Report (AKTR). A designee conducting a
> practical test **must include the failed areas coded on the applicant’s
> knowledge test report to evaluate possible deficiencies which may
> affect the applicant’s flight performance.** Designees are required to
> have a current copy of the Learning Statement Reference Guide for
> Airman Knowledge Testing to review the deficient areas identified on
> the original knowledge test report provided by the applicant. The
> instructor must endorse the applicant’s logbook, training record, or
> bottom of the airman knowledge test, verifying that the applicant has
> received the required training in the deficient areas.

The airlines will look for lots of things in a candidate. Your individual scores may not even be accessible (although you should keep the paperwork on hand). The bigger potential issue busting the whole check ride ([forum link so take it with a grain of salt](https://www.airlinepilotforums.com/career-questions/123870-failed-checkride.html)) as the airlines can see the discontinuance.